# GWT Logging : Send server output to Client

Tags: gwt, logging, client

I'm working with GWT's Logging mechanism to show:

- Client logging output in client's Browser (using com.google.gwt.logging.client.HasWidgetsLogHandler)
- Client logging output in server log (com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl)
- Server logging output in server log (using java.util.logging.*)

Is it reasonable and possible to show server log in a client debug component?

Would you advise to send server logging to client instead of using an extra "tool" to access the server log? Which can be a comfortable realization for detached server logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server-side, you can use any tool you like, obviously... in the client-side, GWT provides all these wonderful options you mentioned, including the RemoteLogger which lets you log stuff going on in the client-side in the server (which is not something you would want to do in production, but for debugging may be helpful).

It's hard to understand why you would need logs to go the other way, ie. from server to client..... maybe you don't have access to the server?? But then how are you going to work on the GWT code, which lives in the server??? Just doesn't add up... if you have access to client logging (be it hosted-mode GWT.log("") messages, production mode java.util.logging, or even the Remote logger), and you have your server logs, you have the whole picture already!

In my opinion, the answer to your question:

> Is it reasonable and possible to show server log in a client debug component?

is simple:

> No, it is not reasonable.

However, if you really must, do it using GWT's RPC mechanism which allows you to send almost anything at all to the client (within the GWT limits, of course), including log messages....